# Can't find the dbo for television series (dbpedia, sparql)

Tags: sql, sparql, dbpedia

I hope you are having a lovely day. I am trying to find all the relationships between two television shows.

Right now, I have

```
SELECT ?r1 ?r2 WHERE {
    
    SELECT ?show1 ?show2 WHERE {
        ?show1 dbo:tvShow dbr:The_Office_(American_TV_series)
        ?show2 dbo:tvShow dbr:The_Office_(British_TV_series)
    }
     
    # Query both ways
    ?show1 ?r1 ?show2 . 
    ?show2 ?r2 ?show1 .      
    
}
```

However, I seem to be getting a syntax error at `?show1` before `dbo:tvShow`.

Does anyone have any advice to fix this query?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: there is no property `dbo:tvShow` - from where do you have this? You should have a look at your example shows to see all available proeperties instead of guessing or inventing stuff. Also, you already have the URIs of both shows which means a triple pattern ` ?show1 dbo:tvShow dbr:The_Office_(American_TV_series)` would result in what for `?show1`? If you just want to get all (direct) relations between both (I doubt there are any), you should use `:SHOW1 ?p :SHOW2` - if you want to get commonalities, you should do `:SHOW1 ?p ?o . :SHOW2 ?p ?o .` - I hope you get the idea

Comment: @UninformedUser the dbo:tvShow property seems to exist  https://dbpedia.org/ontology/tvShow

Comment: Ah, it connects a person to a TV show - didn't know this, nevermind then @Emily - so it now depends on what kind of connection or relation you want to query between both shows. I can see only the `dbo:related` property (and the Wikipedia wikilink) - is this helpful for your task then? There might be "indirect" relations like sharing same moderator or persons, in that case you would have to adapt your query. At least from your initial query you tried to find relations between persons from both TV shows. So this would be "indirect" then. I wouldn't call the variables `?show`, they bind persons

Answer (score 0):

I guess several elements are missing in your query :

- the dot at the end of each pattern in the inner SELECT,
- the curly braces to enclose the inner SELECT,
- the backslash to escape the parenthesis in the IRI of the two tv shows (or the unprefixed IRI).

So the rewritten and valid query could look like this:

```
SELECT ?r1 ?r2 WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?show1 ?show2 WHERE {
        ?show1 dbo:tvShow dbr:The_Office_\(American_TV_series\) .
        ?show2 dbo:tvShow dbr:The_Office_\(British_TV_series\) .
    }
  }

  ?show1 ?r1 ?show2 . 
  ?show2 ?r2 ?show1 .      
}
```

Note that the IRI of the two tv shows can also be written using their unprefixed form, like so:
`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Office_(American_TV_series)>` and `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Office_(British_TV_series)>`.

However I am not sure that your query is correct to find all the relationships between the two TV shows.
Indeed `?show1` and `?show2` variables will be bound to actors of these shows.

To find the direct links between these two shows, in one direction, then in the other, I would advise the following query:

```
SELECT ?r1 ?r2 WHERE {
  BIND(<http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Office_(American_TV_series)> as ?show1) .
  BIND(<http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Office_(British_TV_series)> as ?show2) . 
  {
      ?show1 ?r1 ?show2 .
  } UNION {
      ?show2 ?r2 ?show1 .
  }
}
```